# nodejs head request isn't triggering events

Tags: node.js, http

Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request(
    {
        host: 'example.com',
        method: 'HEAD',
        path: '/'
    },
    function(res){
        res.on('end',function(){
            console.log('Ended');
        }); 
        res.on('finish',function(){
            console.log('Finished');
        }); 
        res.on('close',function(){
            console.log('Closed');
        });
    }
);

req.end();
```

Strange thing about it is that it doesn't print anything. Takes longer than expected and exits. Is this some sort of bug on the nodejs end?

Comment: Maybe there's is just no response. Which host/url are you trying to reach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't declare a `data` or `readable` event handler. According to [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable):

> A Readable stream will not start emitting data until you indicate that you are ready to receive it.

Instead, the stream will be put in a "paused" state indefinitely (until you start reading the data from it), which means that at least the `end` event will never be emitted.

Comment: @Light yeah it's a bit low-level, this.